# Reload model/update template on createRecord save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I see this question is being ask all over again still don't find solution that works for such a trivial task.

This url displays a list of navigations tabs for workspaces.

```
http://localhost:4200/users/1/workspaces
```

Each of tab resolves to

```
http://localhost:4200/users/1/workspaces/:wid
```

Also on the I have a button that suppose to create a new workspace as well as new tab.

Here how controller for looks:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
        newWorkspace: function () {
            this.get('currentModel').reload();
            var self = this;

            var onFail = function() {
                // deal with the failure here
            };

            var onSuccess = function(workspace) {
                self.transitionToRoute('dashboard.workspaces.workspace', workspace.id);
            };

            this.store.createRecord('workspace', {
                title: 'Rails is Omakase'
            }).save().then(onSuccess, onFail);

        }
    }
});
```

When I click on button I see in ember inspector new record indeed created as well as url redirected to id that represents newly created workspace.

My question is how to force model/template to reload. I have already killed 5h trying model.reload() etc. Everything seem not supported no longer. Please please help.

**UPDATE** 
When adding onSuccess

```
model.pushObject(post);
```

throws Uncaught TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should call `this.store.find('workspace', workspace.id)` for Ember Data 1.12.x or earlier. For 1.13 and 2.0 there are more complicated hooks that determine whether or not the browser should query the server again or use a cached value; in that case, call `this.store.findRecord('workspace', workspace.id, { reload: true })`.

Comment: but I have already workspace which is passed to onSuccess. It seems adding this to onSuccess works but looks ugly: model.addObject(workspace._internalModel); @Jonathan

Comment: If you're looking to query the server after updating it then explicitly calling find onSuccess is probably the way to go. I don't think you should use methods/properties that begin with `_`, as they are private API and unstable.

Comment: Seem my hack doesnt want to work when I try to delete items that was created hacky way. When should i call findRecord? Within route or in controller after createRecord. Can you please share more details code snippet? @Jonathan

Comment: self.store.findRecord('workspace', workspace.id, { reload: true });
will return a new record sync with the server. it still doesn't update model which is a set of workspaces. So I need some how to add that record to model, or force model reload completely. @Jonathan

Comment: @Macchiatow: can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bajnyw27/1/ The problem of this solution that I do not have a user id  ( {user: 1} ). It support to be a part of parent route's model.  See in the route a get "modelFor('dashboard')" as user id is not available in nested route @Jonathan

Comment: @Macchiatow: I'm afraid I meant a JSFiddle including all relevant controllers, models, etc. to demonstrate the problem. If you're using Ember CLI, you can use http://ember-twiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this help. I had a similar problem. My action was performed in the route. Refresh function took care of everything.